# How to Load data dynamically to multiselect Option in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vue-multiselect

I need to load the data dynamically to multi select option using VueJs.
I tried lot of ways but nothing is worked for me. this is my codes

```
<multiselect id="webbrand" v-model="upallwebbrand" data-validation="required" data-validate-name="WebBrand"
      :options="webbrands"
      :multiple="true"
       track-by="code"
      :custom-label="websites"
      placeholder="Please select deafult website first">
</multiselect>
```

Vue Function

```
showdata: function (staffid) {
axios.post("/HR/Showdata/", null, { params: { staffid } }).then(function (response) 
{
      hrform.oripassword = response.data.password;
      hrform.upusername = response.data.userdata.UserName;
      hrform.staffid = response.data.userdata.EmployeeId;
      hrform.upselectedteam = response.data.userdata.TeamId;
      hrform.upaccesslevel = response.data.userdata.AccessLevel;
      hrform.upselectedstatus = response.data.userdata.Status;
      hrform.upemail = response.data.userdata.Email;
      **//hrform.upallwebbrand = response.data.userdata.BrandId**

      hrform.upallwebbrand = [{ name: 'Travelcenter', code: 'TCUK' },
                              { name: 'Tour Center', code: 'TOUR' },
                              { name: 'World Airfairs', code: 'WAFR' },
                              { name: 'Mabuhay', code: 'MABU' }];

      hrform.upselectdesignation = response.data.userdata.Designation;

      });
},

websites: function (option) {
    return `${option.name} - ${option.code}`
},
```

In bove function BrandId is coming like this `TCUK,WAFR,TOUR,MABU,` only code with comma separated
I want to make it like below

```
[
 { name: 'Travelcenter', code: 'TCUK' },
 { name: 'Tour Center', code: 'TOUR' },
 { name: 'World Airfairs', code: 'WAFR' },
 { name: 'Mabuhay', code: 'MABU' }
]
```

If assigned values manually like above it's working fine.
I have to do it dynamically How can I achieve this??

Comment: Do you get the brand name ('Travelcenter', 'Tour Center', ...) from server? or you are creating those values only in UI?

Comment: @gilango No I'm not getting those values from database.
we can have those values static

Comment: I am not sure how you can create the array dynamically if you do not know which code belongs to which brand name. You must have hardcoded array for this to work.

Comment: @gilango, that is not proble we can have the brand name hard corded, I want to no how can we create the above mentioned string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm Posting this for future viewers..

```
var hrform = new Vue({
    el: '#hrform',
    data: {
        upselectdesignation:'',
        upallwebbrand : []   //I defined the array like this

    },

});
```

And while updating the `upallwebbrand` getting the codes from database and did the for loop to push the data to array `upallwebbrand` like below

```
showdata: function (staffid) {
    axios.post("/HR/Showdata/", null, { params: { staffid } }).then(function (response) {

        hrform.oripassword = response.data.password;
        hrform.upusername = response.data.userdata.UserName;
        hrform.staffid = response.data.userdata.EmployeeId;
        hrform.upselectedteam = response.data.userdata.TeamId;
        hrform.upaccesslevel = response.data.userdata.AccessLevel;
        hrform.upselectedstatus = response.data.userdata.Status;
        hrform.upemail = response.data.userdata.Email;            
        hrform.upselectdesignation = response.data.userdata.Designation;
        //hrform.branss = response.data.userdata.BrandId;

        var codes = response.data.userdata.BrandId.split(",");  // Spliting the brand Id
        var obj = { 'TCUK': 'Travel Center', 'MABU': 'Mabuhai', 'WAFR': 'World AirFares', 'TOUR': 'Tour Center' }
        hrform.upallwebbrand = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) 
        {
            if (codes[i] in obj) {
               hrform.upallwebbrand.push({ code: codes[i], name: obj[codes[i]] })
            }
        }


    });
}
```

Comment: I would recommend one small change in your logic.... Instead of having too many if..else statements, you can create a key-value pair of code and name.          
  
`var obj = {'TCUK': 'This center', 'MABU': 'Mankarthe', 'WAFR': 'World Arts', 'TOUR': 'Trip Corner'}` .   
Then you can have just 3 lines of code
`for(var i=0; i<codes.length; i++){
 if(codes[i] in obj){
  hrform.upallwebbrand.push({code: codes[i], name: obj[codes[i]]})
    }
} `

Comment: @gilango, thanks for your suggestion, I have update my answer

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume you have 2 arrays, one for name and one for code which is in the right order. You can create an array of objects like this

```
var name_arr = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
var code_arr = ['code1', 'code2', 'code3']
var upallwebbrand = []
for(var i=0; i<name_arr.length; i++){
  upallwebbrand.push({
       name: name_arr[i],
       code: code_arr[i]
    });
}
```

Comment: code is dynamically coming, we can't push like you have done and I want to create string like this

[
 { name: 'Travelcenter', code: 'TCUK' },
 { name: 'Tour Center', code: 'TOUR' },
 { name: 'World Airfairs', code: 'WAFR' },
 { name: 'Mabuhay', code: 'MABU' }
]

Comment: why don't you use `response.data.userdata.BrandId` instead of code_arr? If it's a string with comma, split the string and convert it to an array.

Comment: Thanks! your idea is helped to me that's why I voted up